# How to input Chinese (Zhuyin) on Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: input

I use the Ubuntu 16.04 desktop. I could not find the Chinese (Zuyin, bopomofo) on input source list. How can I add the Chinese (Zhuyin, bopomofo) keyboard?

Answer (score 8):

Chinese input methods and fonts can be easily installed on an English-language Ubuntu system, or any other non-Chinese Ubuntu system. You do not need to install a localized Chinese desktop.

1. Go to **System Settings > Language Support**

   [image: language support settings]
2. When the language support window opens, click <kbd>Install/Remove languages</kbd>

   [image: dialog with language options]
3. Click on *Chinese Simple* and *Chinese Traditional* and then click on <kbd>Apply</kbd>

   [image: check the boxes next to languages to add]
4. Then give your password and authenticate

   [image: password pop up dialog]

   [image: progress dialog applying changes]

   Close the window.
5. Again go to **System Settings > Text Entry**

   [image: settings]
6. Click on the <kbd>+</kbd> icon

   [image: add languages dialog]
7. Select **Chinese (Chewing) (IBus)**

   [image: selected languages available in lisr]

   Close the window.
8. Click on the **EN** icon in the right area of the top menu bar/panel and choose **Chewing**.

   [image: screenshot context menu for input languages]

Now you have Chinese keyboard.

If you couldn't find Chewin in Chinese selections. Try to search 'Chewin' instead of Chinese or Zhuyin.

If there is no Chewin in all options. Then run these commands:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install ibus-chewing
```

Comment: I open Text Entry, there is no Chewing, only Chinese, which installs only zh and it sucks.

Comment: Same here.  There is no Chewing, only Chinese, and there are no Chinese text entry methods.

Comment: Figured out there's another step... you need to log out and back in to see the extra "Chinese (IBus)" options

Answer (score 0):

[image]

See the picture above.

1. open Ubuntu software
2. search ibus to find ibus preferences
3. active it and check 2nd tab(type in function?)=>add Zhuyin
4. the reset steps is System Settings --> Text Entry and add Zhuyin

Comment: I don't see Zhuyin or Chinese in the Input Method Add.  (I already have Chinese added under Language Support.)

Answer (score 0):

The question is well-answered by the most voted answer.

For those who couldn't find the Zhuyin or Chewing, try in terminal

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install ibus-chewing
```