# Typing zhuyin chinese transliteration symbols

Tags: keyboard-layout, input-language, chinese, fcitx

I want to type zhuyin symbols.

For example:
ㄓㄨˋ ㄧㄣ

The only ways I know to do this currently are:

1. Via Cangjie IME [yyyxo yyyxw　yyyyo yyyxv　yyyyi]
2. via http://www.sciweavers.org/i2type/zhuyin-keyboard

I'm looking for a built-in `fcitx` keyboard or some similar native tool to type according to the zhuyin keyboard layout. (i.e. [5j4 up] for ㄓㄨˋ ㄧㄣ）

Does anyone know of one?

The zhuyin keyboard layout is as follows:

```
1 ㄅ
q ㄆ
a ㄇ
z ㄈ
2 ㄉ
w ㄊ
s ㄋ
x ㄌ
e ㄍ
d ㄎ
c ㄏ
r ㄐ
f ㄑ
v ㄒ
5 ㄓ
t ㄔ
g ㄕ
b ㄖ
y ㄗ
h ㄘ
n ㄙ
u ㄧ
j ㄨ
m ㄩ
8 ㄚ
i ㄛ
k ㄜ
, ㄝ
9 ㄞ
o ㄟ
l ㄠ
. ㄡ
0 ㄢ
p ㄣ
; ㄤ
/ ㄥ
- ㄦ
6 ˊ
3 ˇ
4 ˋ
7 ˙
```

For now, I just added those shorter zhuyin-keyboard based codes to my cangjie table.
So I can currently type ㄓㄨˋ　ㄧㄣ with [5 j24  u2p2]

But I'm still wondering if anyone knows of an extant built-in zhuyin keyboard that can type ㄓㄨˋ ㄧㄣ with [5j4 up]?

I made a customzhuyin.mb and customzhuyin.conf file for　`fcitx` but I'm not sure how to actually add them to the input methods list?

I added a Taiwanese keyboard that just types English, but I don't see where I can edit it.

Does anyone know where all the `fcitx` keyboards files are to edit them?

Thanks.

Comment: Does [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/812139/349837) help you? Did you installed `ibus-chewing` package?

Comment: Thanks Pablo for your reply. I had seen that page. I have chewing input installed and can use it to type Chinese characters. But I'm trying to type just zhuyin phonetic symbols. For example ㄓㄨˋ　ㄧㄣ. Typing those symbols on chewing only outputs 注音.